# Routing Error for assets Rails 3.2.8 on Upgrading Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Its really frustrating to see the routing errors for stylesheets, images when I upgrade to 3.2.8 from 3.1.1 Rails. Tried the "bundle exec rails server" command and also  tried a adding the gems in the file one by one, did not work too :(

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
```

Answer (score 1):

When linking to assets in rails, always use `asset_path`, `asset_url`, or one of the helper functions that call these in turn (`image_path`, `image_url`, `javascript_include_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag`).

In your case, it looks like you hardcoded `/stylesheets/application.css` in your application layout. Simple change that code to something like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

and it should correctly point to `/assets/application.css` for development, and `/assets/application-<sha1 hash>.css` in production (when assets are compiled).

Also, if you have the assets compiled locally (if you have anything in `public/assets` this is the case. You may want to `rm -rf public/assets` if you're developing locally), then you need the following line in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "start/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" %>
This how it is in my application.html.erb, worked fine on rails 3.1

Comment: okay, I updated the answer with some more info. I'm guessing here that you have files in `public/assets`. It may also be that some of these files have hardcoded links in them, although it's hard to imagine that the link would be to application.css.

Comment: I had this to the gem file 'group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end'
removing the "group :assets do"  worked

Comment: Sounds like you weren't loading assets as part of development environment (unless you're running in 'production' env locally?). Try using this line in config/application.rb: `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))`

Comment: Its an app more than a year old, so yeah I have not done anything specific to dev or prod. Thanks